# How to create multiple new columns with data.table's j over different subsets

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I want to create multiple variables that are aggregating various subsets of a dataset. For an illustrating example, say you have the following data:

```
DT = data.table(Group1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4), 
                Group2 = c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2), 
                  Var1 = c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

I want to find several averages of variable `Var1`. I want to know:

- `mean(Var1)` grouped by `Group1`
- `mean(Var1)` for only those with `Group2 == 1`, grouped by `Group1`
- `mean(Var1)` for only those with `Group2 == 2`, grouped by `Group1`

Or, in data.table parlance,

```
DT[, mean(Var1), by=Group1]
DT[Group2==1, mean(Var1), by=Group1]
DT[Group2==2, mean(Var1), by=Group1]
```

Obviously, calculating any one of these is very straightforward. But I can't find a good way to calculate all three of them, since they use different subsets in `i`. The solution I've been using so far is generating them individually, then merging them into a unified table.

```
DT_all <- DT[, .(avgVar1_all = mean(Var1)), by = Group1]
DT_1 <- DT[Group2 == 1, .(avgVar1_1 = mean(Var1)), by = Group1]
DT_2 <- DT[Group2 == 2, .(avgVar1_2 = mean(Var1)), by = Group1]
group_info <- merge(DT_all, DT_1, by = "Group1")
group_info <- merge(group_info, DT_2, by = "Group1")

group_info
#    Group1 avgVar1_all avgVar1_1 avgVar1_2
# 1:      1         0.4 0.6666667 0.0000000
# 2:      2         0.6 1.0000000 0.3333333
# 3:      3         0.2 0.2500000 0.0000000
# 4:      4         0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Is there a more elegant method I could be using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do it all in one grouping operation using `.SD`:

```
DT[, .(
        all  = mean(Var1),
        grp1 = .SD[Group2==1, mean(Var1)],
        grp2 = .SD[Group2==2, mean(Var1)]
      ),
  by = Group1,
  .SDcols=c("Group2","Var1")
  ]

#   Group1 all      grp1      grp2
#1:      1 0.4 0.6666667 0.0000000
#2:      2 0.6 1.0000000 0.3333333
#3:      3 0.2 0.2500000 0.0000000
#4:      4 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Comment: This does the trick, although isn't subsetting .SD generally frowned upon, for performance? Or is that just taking a subset of columns from .SD?

Comment: @ConnorJ - I'm far from an authority on the subject, but I think `.SD` subsetting has been optimised a lot since that was an issue. Happy to be slapped-up-the-side-of-the-head by Arun or Matt if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ConnorJ - now that I look up some details, maybe you're right and this isn't ideal - https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/735

Comment: Yeah, it works, (and isn't unworkably slow), but perhaps is suboptimal. I used `.SDcols` to make it as quick as possible, which helped. It's odd, I see examples of why to not subset `.SD`, but they always look like `.SD[, someCol]`, rather than `.SD[someRows]`. Not sure if the latter is more acceptable, but since we have both `i` and `j` it's not great, per your link. *shrug*

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reshape2::dcast`:

```
reshape2::dcast(DT, Group1 ~ Group2, fun=mean, margins="Group2")


  Group1         1         2 (all)
1      1 0.6666667 0.0000000   0.4
2      2 1.0000000 0.3333333   0.6
3      3 0.2500000 0.0000000   0.2
4      4 0.0000000 0.0000000   0.0
```

@thelatmail noted in a comment below that this approach does not scale well. Eventually, [`margins` should be available](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/531) in data.table's `dcast`, which will probably be more efficient.

An ugly workaround:

```
DT[, c(
  dcast(.SD, Group1 ~ Group2, fun=mean), 
  all = .(dcast(.SD, Group1 ~ ., fun=mean)$.)
)]


   Group1         1         2 all
1:      1 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.4
2:      2 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.6
3:      3 0.2500000 0.0000000 0.2
4:      4 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0
```

Comment: Very neat code, but it seems to choke on really big data. I tested it on 10M records and it ate nearly all 16GB of my RAM before I killed it.

Comment: Good to know, @thelatemail, thanks. Guess we should look forward to the data.table implementation in that case.

Comment: Yeah, my real dataset is about 3M rows, so I'll hold out for data.table's `dcast` to get this going. Thanks!